# C boolean type function always returns FALSE

Tags: c

My assignment is to make a program that takes a string and output:

```
the number of characters in the string
the number of vowels in the string
the number of UPPERCASE letters in the string
the number of lowercase letters in the string
the number of other characters in the string
```

We are not allowed to use the ctype.h library.
Right now I'm just trying to output the number of vowels.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

bool isVowel(char *c);

int main(){
    char userString[5];
    int i;
    int vowelCount;
    char *c;
        printf("enter string:");
        scanf("%c", userString);
            for(i=0; i<= 4; ++i){
                userString[i] = *c;
                isVowel(c);
                if(isVowel(c)){
                    vowelCount = vowelCount + 1;
                }
            }
    printf("%d\n", vowelCount);
return 0;
}

bool isVowel(char *c){
    if(*c == 'a' || *c == 'A' || *c == 'e' || *c == 'E' || *c == 'i' || *c 
== 'I' || *c == 'o' || *c == 'O' || *c == 'u' || *c == 'U' ){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

I believe that isVowel is always returning false because, when I run it with the input "test!",I get this:

```
enter string: test!
0
```

Comment: You believe? You’d know for sure if you got your debugger out.

Comment: @Bathsheba When I ran it in the debugger and I got to the part in the loop where it reached the character 'e' the value of vowelCount was 0.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I do not believe using a debugger would resolve this person’s belief. First, it would reveal the routine’s behavior only in the few cases in which it is called in this program, not all cases. Second, it is not at all clear it would reveal to this person the actual issue, since a user new to the debugger does not yet know how to use it to illuminate such things. Comments such as that are snide and often offputting to people. They are unkind. You can guide people to learning in gentle ways.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: As you probably know I have you down as one of the smartest on the C and C++ tags; if not the smartest. But, I think you could put that intellectualism to better use: you and I both know that being able to use a debugger is more important than knowing how to type code, and read code! My initial comment, for what it’s worth, is written in typical Cantabrigian humour. No offence is meant.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Certainly knowing how to use a debugger is a greatly useful skill. But it does not come from brusque comments to use a debugger. Suggesting to OP that they examine the value of `c` when the routine is called and compare it to the value of the buffer (address) or examine what it points to would be more tutorial. It conveys a sense of guiding a person to knowledge (here is how to do it) instead of suggesting they have neglected a duty (you messed up). I agree your intent was not to offend, but humans may still be put off by such statements regardless of intent.

Answer (score 1):

You're not setting the `c` variable. I suspect this line:

```
userString[i] = *c;
```

should be something like:

```
c = userString + i;
```

Comment: Yes, looks like this. But there is no reason to use `char *` argument for `isVowel`, so that `char ch;` and `ch = userString[i]; isVowel(ch);` is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

This is your code with some corrections:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

bool isVowel(char c);

int main(){
    char userString[5];
    int i;
    int vowelCount=0;
    char c;
        printf("enter string:");
        scanf("%s", userString); // %s
            for(i=0; i<= 4; ++i){
                c=userString[i] ;              
              printf("%c",c);

                if(isVowel(c)){
                    vowelCount = vowelCount + 1;
                } 
            }
    printf("%d\n", vowelCount);
return 0;
}

bool isVowel(char c){
    return (c == 'a' || c == 'A' || c == 'e' || c == 'E' || c == 'i' || 
    c == 'I' || c == 'o' || c == 'O' || c == 'u' || c == 'U' ) ; 
}
```

Comment: Merely supplying corrected code with no explanation does not answer a question.

Comment: @Eric I left it as an exercice. He may ask again. But some times it is better not to explain and let him find out.

Comment: Thank you to manoliar, jon-hanson, ReAl and Eric Postpischil it works now! However, I'm still a bit confused. Earlier when I was compiling it I was getting a lot of errors saying that it expects arguments of type char * so why were the '*'s not needed? I'm still a bit confused on how pointers work.